XML get node where value is exists in node
From a database I select the XML below.
In this XML, I want to select the node where a specific value exists inside a node.
So for example: with in the XML I search for nodes where the node ArtNr = 209232. If the value exists then the query must return the value inside the node <ArtDesc> and the value inside the node <QTY> (here: CP 01 Fans and 1.0000000000).
For checking if the ArtNr exists, I use the following command in my WHERE clause
info_TOL_ArticleList.exist('(/*:LIST/*:ELEMENTS/*:TOL_Article/*:fields/*:ArtNr[.="209232"])') = 1

This is the XML I'm working with:
<LIST>
  <ELEMENTS>
    <TOL_Article>
      <fields>
        <ArtDesc>Looprooster L1100xW1100x2mm Mesh 33,33x33,33</ArtDesc>
        <ArtNr>515021111</ArtNr>
        <BasePrice>153.7500</BasePrice>
        <Qty>3.0000000000</Qty>
        <Sort />
        <Unit>st</Unit>
      </fields>
    </TOL_Article>
    <TOL_Article>
      <fields>
        <ArtDesc>FP Box</ArtDesc>
        <ArtNr>595224</ArtNr>
        <BasePrice>100.0000</BasePrice>
        <Qty>5.0000000000</Qty>
        <Sort />
        <Unit>st</Unit>
      </fields>
    </TOL_Article>
    <TOL_Article>
      <fields>
        <ArtDesc>Cable assembly Fused</ArtDesc>
        <ArtNr>595225</ArtNr>
        <BasePrice>110.0000</BasePrice>
        <Qty>5.0000000000</Qty>
        <Sort />
        <Unit>st</Unit>
      </fields>
    </TOL_Article>
    <TOL_Article>
      <fields>
        <ArtDesc>CP 01 Fans</ArtDesc>
        <ArtNr>209232</ArtNr>
        <BasePrice>4300.0000</BasePrice>
        <Qty>1.0000000000</Qty>
        <Sort />
        <Unit>st</Unit>
      </fields>
    </TOL_Article>
  </ELEMENTS>
</LIST>


So what have you tried? Why wasn't it working for you?

Your xml doesn't have any namespaces, so using : in your xpath without namespaces being defined will result in an error.
More correct would be: info_TOL_ArticleList.exist('/LIST/ELEMENTS/TOL_Article[fields/ArtNr="209232"]') = 1
SELECT
    info_TOL_ArticleList.value('(/LIST/ELEMENTS/TOL_Article[fields/ArtNr="209232"]/fields/ArtDesc)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS ArtDesc,
    info_TOL_ArticleList.value('(/LIST/ELEMENTS/TOL_Article[fields/ArtNr="209232"]/fields/Qty)[1]', 'DECIMAL(18,10)') AS Qty
FROM
    XML_DATA
WHERE
    info_TOL_ArticleList.exist('/LIST/ELEMENTS/TOL_Article[fields/ArtNr="209232"]') = 1;

Output:



ArtDesc
Qty




CP 01 Fans
1.0000000000



fiddle

The OP picked a very inefficient answer.

ok. thank you for your feedback.

That's the truth. There is no need to apply the same XPath predicate many times. Also, there is no need to apply repetitive long XPath expressions every single time.

Thank you. I wanted to make as little correction to the asker's inital attempt as I could, to point out where they went wrong.

Perfect answer.
Is it also possible to use a like in the where clause?
So something like :
WHERE
info_TOL_ArticleList.exist('/LIST/ELEMENTS/TOL_Article[fields/ArtNr LIKE "20923%"]') = 1;

As noted in the other answer, for an empty namespace you shouldn't put :, just leave it out.
A more performant version in the case where you need to query the same node in multiple places in the query, is to use the .nodes Table-Valued function
You should also use /text() instead of relying on implicit atomization in .value.
SELECT
    article.value('(ArtDesc/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS ArtDesc,
    article.value('(Qty/text())[1]', 'DECIMAL(18,10)') AS Qty
FROM
    XML_DATA xd
CROSS APPLY xd.info_TOL_ArticleList.nodes('
    /LIST/ELEMENTS/TOL_Article/fields [(ArtNr/text()) = "209232"]
') x1(article);

db<>fiddle

Good answer. +1 from my side.

Perfect answer. Is it also possible to use a like in the where clause? So something like : WHERE info_TOL_ArticleList.exist('/LIST/ELEMENTS/TOL_Article[fields/ArtNr LIKE "20923%"]') = 1;

Yes sure try [fn:substring((ArtNr/text())[1], 1, 6) = "209232"] see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/functions-on-string-values-substring?view=sql-server-ver16 unfortunately only fn:contains is supported not fn:starts-with or fn:ends-with
